# Where to find browser statistics?

Tags: browser, statistics

I know about [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) statistics, but it much differs from the one on my company's site.

Comment: The question seems to be a bit unclear. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: [`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers)

Comment: Percentage of browsers people using, their name and version.

Comment: Just interesting what so bad in this question to be voted down...?

Comment: Its very subjective and there is no "complete" answer.  The best you can do is aggregate data from a variety of sources.  To be honest if Google reported stats for access to their search engine I would take those as a very definitive breakdown ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**It all depends on the content and the audience.**

On a tech blog about Web Technologies expect a breakdown like:

```
Firefox:           65%
Internet Explorer: 19%
Chrome:             8%
Safari:             5%
Opera:              2%
Other:              1%
```

But if you are selling yarn to the local knitting community expect a breakdown like:

```
Internet Explorer: 88%
Firefox:            6%
Safari:             3%
Chrome:             2%
Opera:              1%
Other:              1%
```

Your best bet is to add [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) to your site and track what stats reflect **your** audience.

Keep in mind that if your site is *broken* in any given browser - expect that percentage to drop... not because there is no audience but because they can't access your content.

Also note that time-of-day matters too.  Many visitors are forced to use browser X (typically IE6 or IE7) at work - but at home they use the browser of their choice.

Since most questions about browser stats are to determine if you need to (add/remove) support for browser X, is there a browser in particular that you want more data on? e.g. **cough, cough** IE6?

Answer (score 0):

The w3schools statistics are not very representative as they only measure accesses to their site. In that case it is no surprise that your company's site has different statistics from that. It all depends on the intended audience and the usage shares in that audience. You'll get widely varying results for different sites, always. That's why useful statistics measure over many different ones.

As David Johnstone pointed out, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers) is a good start.